# broadcasting/auth 500 pusher in laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

In my app i using from pusher to send notification for typists.but i giving this error:

```
Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500
```

javascript codes of pusher placed in footer:

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
  Pusher.logToConsole = true;

  var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
      cluster: 'ap2',
      encrypted: true,
  authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth",
  auth: {
      params: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
            .attr('content')
      }
  }
  });

  var channel = pusher.subscribe(
    'private-App.Typist.' + {{$typistId}}
  );

  channel.bind('NewTypeOrder', function(data) {
      alert('hi');
  });
```

in channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Typist.{id}', function (Typist $typist, $id) {
    return true;
});
```

and in Events/EventTypeOrder.php

```
class NewTypeOrder implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $typist;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Typist $typist)
{
    $this->typist = $typist;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('App.Typist.' . $this->typist->id);
}
}
```

my typists table is quite from users table and laravel authentication for typist not used because laravel authentication just used for users only.

in laravel.log

```
[2018-07-22 20:27:38] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Key file 
"file://C:\xampp\htdocs\samane_typax_5.4\storage\oauth-public.key" 
permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 666 in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\samane_typax_5.4\vendor\league\oauth2- 
server\src\CryptKey.php:57
Stack trace:
```

Now what can i do for this issue?

Comment: Show the bottom ~50 rows of `./storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: make sure you have <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> in head section.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka yes i added csrf-token meta

Comment: the last 50 lines or so, not all of it :)

Comment: @Quezler the logs is long and i can't put them here

Comment: try removing  auth: {
      params: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
            .attr('content')
      }
  }

Comment: @Quezler #59 C:\xampp\htdocs\samane_typax_5.4\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 C:\xampp\htdocs\samane_typax_5.4\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 C:\xampp\htdocs\samane_typax_5.4\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

Comment: please edit the original answer, the comments have a size limit

Comment: @ManoharKhadka I removed auth object but showed that error again

Comment: @Quezler updated question

Comment: @SaeedHemmati i need to see the lines just above `#0`, should start with a timestamp e.g. `[2018-07-24 08:32:19]`

Comment: @Quezler thank you. question updated

Comment: @SaeedHemmati allright, i've added a possible fix below :)

Answer (score 0):

On the commandline, type: `php artisan tinker`

Then paste the following:

`chmod(storage_path('oauth-public.key'), 0660)`

This should set the right file permissions, the error should vanish/change once enter is pressed :)

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1/broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on private-App.Typist.11 for pusher:subscription_error